# Can Ubuntu hard drives be swapped

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, swap

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on an SSD on a Thinkpad T430. Can I just pop it out and put it in my new T470, or do I need to do a complete new install on a separate drive for the T470? In general, are hard drives with only Ubuntu on them interchangeable to and from heterogeneous machines?

Comment: I have several times swapped dual 0S SSD's from Laptop n Desktops.. some times worked.. sometimes not.. i guess its based on MB compatibility but not sure.. you must be ready with alternatives if it does not boot after swapping..

Comment: Dual 0S I mean W10 n U18.04

Comment: I'm sorry but I meant I have just U19.10 on the SSD and I want to take it physically out of the one machine and put it in the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on an SSD on a Thinkpad T430. Can I just pop it out and put it in my new T470,

Yes. With 1 comment: remove all 3rd party drivers.

The 2 important 3rd party components are the display driver and the NIC driver. If the display in both is the same you can keep the display driver but it is better to re-install it. Same for the NIC: if the NIC is the same or in the same chipset range it is likely to work.

> or do I need to do a complete new install on a separate drive for the T470? In general, are hard drives with only Ubuntu on them interchangeable to and from heterogeneous machines?

No an yes. Linux/Ubuntu recreates the devices on every boot so it will notice the changes and adjust accordingly.

Comment: So if I'm not using 3rd party video or NIC drivers Ubuntu should just make the adjustment from machine to machine on the fly. The Thinkpads in question use generic Intel video I believe.

Comment: Yes, I do that once every other month or so.